# How Submit form by div group

Tags: laravel-8

```
<div>
  <div>
    <input name="item[]" >
    <input name="part[]" >
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="part[]" >
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <input name="item[]" >
    <input name="part[]" >
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="part[]" >
  </div>
</div>
```

need output

[item_name] => Array
(
[0] => item_01
[1] => item_02
)

[part_name] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => B
)
[1] => Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => B
)
)